# Como puedo ocultar un padre en un OrgChart

Tags: javascript, chart.js, google-visualization

Podría alguien ayudarme y decirme como ocultar el padre  y seguir mostrando el hijo en un organigrama.

Ejemplo:
Es requerido ocultar el padre ('SG001') y seguir mostrando al hijo ('AA014'), dándole continuidad a la linea y dejando al hijo en el nivel que le corresponde.

```js
google.charts.load('current', {packages:["orgchart"]});
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Name');
        data.addColumn('string', 'Manager');
        data.addColumn('string', 'ToolTip');

        // For each orgchart box, provide the name, manager, and tooltip to show.
  data.addRows([
     [{v:'SD001', f:'EMBRIONES CALLEJO,V RICARDO<div style="color:blue; font-style:italic">SUBDIR. COM. DE PETS CONTROL</div>'},'', '0'],
     [{v:'SG001', f:'<div style="color:blue; font-style:italic">SUBGTE. INTELIGENCIA ARTIFICIAL</div>'},'SD001', '1'],
     [{v:'GT002', f:'HERNANDEZ,E<div style="color:blue; font-style:italic">GTE. DE RELACIONES</div>'},'SD001', '1'],
     [{v:'GT034', f:'<div style="color:blue; font-style:italic">GTE. DE VENTAS </div>'},'SD001', '1'],
     [{v:'AA014', f:'ALFAGUAROO ,ALAN <div style="color:blue; font-style:italic">ANALISTA A</div>'},'GT034', '2'],
     [{v:'AA026', f:'CRUZ,JULIA<div style="color:blue; font-style:italic">ANALISTA A</div>'},'GT002', '2'],
     [{v:'SG002', f:'MORALES ,AZUCENA <div style="color:blue; font-style:italic">SUBGTE. RELACIONES DIV</div>'},'GT002', '2']
  ]);

  //data.setRowProperty(1, 'selectedStyle', 'background-color:#00FF00');
        //data.setProperty(0, 0, "style", "font-style:bold; font-size:22px;");
        //data.removeColumn(3);
        //data.setColumnProperty(1, name, value)
        data.setProperty(1, 1, 'style', 'background-color: red;');


  //var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
    //view.setRows(data.getFilteredRows([
    //  {column: 0, Value: SG001}
    //]));


        // Create the chart.
        var chart = new google.visualization.OrgChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));


        function selectHandler() {
          var selectedItem = chart.getSelection()[0];
          if (selectedItem) {
            var topping = data.getValue(selectedItem.row, 0);
            //data.removeColumn(selectedItem.row);
            //alert('The user selected ' + topping);
          }
        }
        google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', selectHandler);

        // Draw the chart, setting the allowHtml option to true for the tooltips.
        //chart.setView({columns: 1});
        chart.draw(data, {allowHtml:true, allowCollapse:true});
        //chart.hideColumns(4,false);
        chart.collapse(2,true);
        chart.collapse(3,true);
        chart.collapse(4,true);
      }
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
<button type="button" id="hideSales"  >Hide Sales</button>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si pero el requerimiento es que quede bajo un padre y en un siguiente nivel , al eliminar el padre los hijos quedan fuera del organigrama al perder su ruta o responsable directo.

Comment: Pues son ambos requerimientos, si claro agrego la imagen.

Comment: El requerimiento funcional es poder mostrar un organigrama que permita ocultar algunos padres en base a un perfil en especifico de su puesto y nivel. El requerimiento técnico es integrar dentro de google.visualization.OrgChart dicha funcionalidad.

Comment: En realidad la organización en este momento pasa a segundo termino ya que esa es generada por la información de cada empleado, lo requerido es la la linea de código o método para ocultar en este caso el padre o caja que lo contiene, gracias.

Comment: ¿Quieres decir que Alfaguardo, Alan puede mostrarse en el segundo nivel?

Comment: No  Alfaguardo, Alan debe de mantener su nivel asignado, solo se debe de ocultar GTE VENTAS, la imagen deberá de mostrarse tal y como es el ejemplo de Requerido.

Answer (score 0):

Según se ve en la imagen, se requiere que los puestos están organizados por filas,donde cada fila corresponde al nivel/tipo de puesto, operativos fila inferior, mandos medios, fila media, alta gerencia, fila superior. Creo que con OrgChart de Google no va a ser sencillo, es cosa que experimentes con las opciones que se indican en la [documentación oficial](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/orgchart) o bien que uses algunos "hacks" como sobreponer una imagen que oculte el puesto y conecte las líneas.

Por ejemplo, puedes usar `nodeClass` para que mediante CSS hagas transparente la caja del GTE. DE VENTAS. Donde surge mi principal duda es en dibujar la línea de la parte superior con la parte inferior. Otra opción, ya mencionada, es sobre poner una imagen de tal forma que tape la caja del GTE. de VENTAS.